# beautifulsoup find text with and without regex

Tags: beautifulsoup

The html:

```
<td>some key
</td>
```

find without regex:

```
soup.find(text='some key')
```

returned None

find with regex

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('some key'))
```

returned the td node.

Would anyone point out the difference between the two approaches?   "some key" is a literal string without special characters.  I noted that there's a carriage return at the end of "some key" that `</td>` appears on the next line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beautifulsoup uses == to match the content between tags and the search string.  Since `'some key\r\n'` != `'some key'`, the search failed.